# jQuery .html() returning undefined despite being defined earlier in the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have started using jQuery recently and have bumped into a problem. in a function, i use the .html() method as a substitute to innerHTML (which from what i've seen in the documentation, isn't wrong), but for some reason when i try to check the value i'm setting, it gives me undefined. here's my code:

```js
let nuevo_producto = $("li").html(() => { return "<input class='marcar-comprado' type='checkbox'/><span class='producto'>" + nombre + "</span><img class='icono-borrar' src='img/delete-icon.png' alt='Borrar'>"});

console.log(nuevo_producto.html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: your code works

Comment: Why are you setting `.html(() =>)` while you should set it directly to that string

Comment: @itGoldman You have actually created side effect to OP question. If there is no actual HTML to work with, then OP question actually provides `undefined` result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are selecting actual DOM element `<li>`.

If you want to create virtual element, you should pass not selector, but it's content:

```js
let nombre = 'Product 1';
let nuevo_producto = $("<li>").html(() => { return "<input class='marcar-comprado' type='checkbox'/><span class='producto'>" + nombre + "</span><img class='icono-borrar' src='img/delete-icon.png' alt='Borrar'>"});

console.log(nuevo_producto.html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Best practice would still be to use `$('<li></li>')` tho (and define the inside html in the tag directly)